# fullcalendar event title in month view is object Object

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

when I add event:

```
var newEvent = new Object();

newEvent.title = "some text";
newEvent.start = new Date();
newEvent.allDay = false;
$('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent );
```

in month view I don't see title but object Object

I found more info - this is html of event in month view.

```
<div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">object Object</span> <span class="fc-title">dd</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Greg Hmhmm, did you found a solution for that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, the documentation said that we need to pass the event object argument, so I suggest that you can try with a literal object like this:

```
var newEvent = {
      title: 'some text',
      start: new Date(),
      allDay: false
};
```

Note that start time must be a Moment.js convertable string. See more:

> **start:** The date/time an event begins. Required. A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this will become a real Moment object.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/

Answer (score -1):

For me, it displays "object Object" when the UI configuration has `displayEventTime: true`. Set it to `false`.

```
displayEventTime: false,
```